# Firebase realtime database permission error even though rules playground simulation succeeds

Tags: python, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

My database has a `users` child with fields `email` and `name`, with the key being the users uid. Here are the database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
     "users": {
       "$uid": { 
         "email": {
           ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
           ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
        },
         "name": {
           ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
           ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using pyrebase to access the firebase project. Here is the statement that tries to add them to `users`:

```
db.child("users").child(self.user["localId"]).set({"name": name, "email" : email})
```

While creating a new user, I get a permission denied error. The user is still able to sign in though. When I make a simulated request with the rules playground, it succeeds.

edit: Here is a reproducible example:

```py
import pyrebase

config = {
    "apiKey": "",
    "authDomain": "",
    "projectId": "",
    "databaseURL": "",
    "storageBucket": "",
    "messagingSenderId": "",
    "appId": "",
    "measurementId": "",
}
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
user = firebase.auth().sign_in_with_email_and_password("test@gmail.com", "password")
db = firebase.database()
db.child("users").child(user["localId"]).set({"name": "test", "email": "test@gmail.com"}, token=user["localId"])
```

Comment: Is your `db` object a Purebase instance? If so, are you sure it is signed in with the same user as `self.user["localId"]`, or with a service account?

Comment: Hmm... I'm also wondering: can you try using `update` instead of `set`?

Comment: The db object comes from `pyrebase.initialize_app(config).db()`. I have tried to explicitly passing the users token to both a `set` and `update` request but it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you initialize Pyrebase with a service account as shown in the second code snippet here: https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#add-pyrebase-to-your-application? It's probably better to edit your question to show a [complete-yet-minimal  Python/Pyrebase script with which we can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user ID (`user["localId"]`) shouldn't be passed in as the authentication token. You need to pass the user's ID token instead (`user["idToken"]`). So while you may be writing to the correct location, you are doing so without providing the right authorization.

```py
db.child("users").child(user["localId"]).set({"name": "test", "email": "test@gmail.com"}, user["idToken"])
```

Comment: It works now. That you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be write their own `name` and `email`, but no other properties, the more idiomatic way to do that would be:

```
 "users": {
   "$uid": { 
     ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
     ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
     "email": {
       ".validate": true
     },
     "name": {
       ".validate": true
     },
     "$other": {
       ".validate": false
     }
  }
}
```

So we authorize writing for the entire `/users/$uid` node here only once, and then determine what individual child properties are valid under there, and disallow all other properties.

Comment: I tried using these rules, but it gives the same permission denied error, but the rules playground simulation works.